# Wordpress Mysql query to replace empty alt img with post_title

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have several empty img alt on my wordpress site (about 3k).
After considering different solutions, looks like the best approach is to do a replace on the database.
I would like to replace empty alt in post_content (alt="") with post_title (alt="This is the post title").

Something like that:

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = REPLACE(post_content,'alt=""', 'alt=" + post_title + "') 
where post_status = 'publish';
```

But I don't get how to insert the post_title value in the query.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a query like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
set post_content = 
  REPLACE(post_content,'alt=""', CONCAT('alt="', post_title, '"')) 
WHERE post_status = 'publish';
```

and for a specific lenght use SUBSTRING()

```
UPDATE wp_posts
set post_content = 
  REPLACE(post_content,'alt=""', CONCAT('alt="', SUBSTRING(post_title,1,20), '"')) 
WHERE post_status = 'publish';
```

Comment: I need to set a specific lenght for the post_title value. 
I don't want to replace the empty alt img with the entire post_title, but let's say only 20 characters.
How can I obtain the desired result?

Comment: @hhh - i have change my answer